# Build Maven with Dependencies

Tags: java, mysql, maven

Is it possible to build a Maven project so the that the dependencies are included in the output of the building process. For example. If I am using the MySQL connector in my project, the jar file for the connector and its dependencies become part of the output so I can zip everything and give it to another person and the project will work immediately with out the need for maven.

I am using two dependencies in my project: jwbf and mysql-connector-javaHere is the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.nif.neurolex</groupId>
    <artifactId>BulkChange</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwbf</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.nif.neurolex.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Are you looking for help getting it to work (in which case, please provide what you've got so far and what's not working), or just for a thumbs-up that you won't hit a dead-end if you go down this path?

Comment: If you could point me to how achieve my goal, that will be great. I am using two dependencies in my project: jwbf and mysql-connector-java.

Comment: I haven't used it, but the [Maven Dependencies Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) should do what you want.  I've only used Maven to build WARs using the WAR plugin, which includes dependencies when it makes the WAR, so if all else fails you could build a WAR and then extract the dependency JARs from it, but that should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to package your code with all the necessary dependency jars together so that the build target is self contained.

If so, then yes. Check out Maven Assembly Plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Since the output can be tar or zip, you can even include scripts and directories in your package (such as bin/*.sh to run your application or tools). The permissions of the scripts can be set at build time in the assembly descriptor.